# Error in Plaid Tutorial Live Interactive Coding

Tags: interactive, live, plaid

I just login into Plaid and trying the live interactive coding in https://plaid.com/tutorials/basics/
after the project is loaded and I click View App, it will hit

> server IP address could not be found.

Please help what should I do

Comment: Have you tried clicking the "Reset Saved Project" in the gear menu in the upper right? Try that, and then maybe reload the page, and let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: It's still occured and displaying 
slash-zealous-crowley.glitch.me’s server IP address could not be found.

Comment: anyone can help on this issue or anyone can running the live code apps ?
cc @ToddKerpelman

Comment: I wonder if perhaps that site is being blocked for you. If you just open up a new browser and go to https://slash-zealous-crowley.glitch.me/, does it work?